# ¿Cómo obtener la ip de un dominio en Java y convertirlo a string?

Tags: java, eclipse

Hola estaba intentando obtener la ip de un dominio usando `inetaddress` lo que hago es:

```
InetAddress giriAddress = InetAddress.getByName("www.girionjava.com");
```

Pero cuando lo hago me devuelve los siguientes errores:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files    ProcessCommand.java /ActivityAndrorat/src/my/app/activityclient line 1  Java Problem
Default constructor cannot handle exception type UnknownHostException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor LauncherActivity.java   /Androrat/src/my/app/client line 26 Java Problem
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project    ActivityAndrorat        Unknown Java Problem
The type sun.management.OperatingSystemImpl is not visible  VideoPanel.java /AndroratServer/src/gui/panel   line 36 Java Problem
```

Aunque incorpore la librería inetaddress a mi proyecto sigue sin funcionar ¿cómo podría incluirlo correctamente para poder obtener la dirección IP del dominio y luego hacer la conversión a string?

La captura es:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir una captura de la pestaña "Librerías" a tu pregunta?

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta y pruba de nuevo. Que se había olvidado poner que borraras el JRE y lo añadieses de nuevo. Asegúrate de que es la versión de java con la has creado el proyecto.

Comment: OK. ¿Has probado lo de eliminar el jre y añadirlo de nuevo?

Answer (score 1):

Parece que es un problema del eclipse y el JRE que estás usando. Prueba a cerrar y abrir el proyecto y hacer un clean del mismo.

Si no funciona, prueba lo siguiente:

- Clic con el botón derecho en el proyecto -> Java Build Path
- Pestaña Librerias
- Buscar la entrada JRE librería del sistema y borrarla.
- Clic en añadir liberia. Añadir el JRE correcto.

Comment: le añado el JRE y me lo sigue mostrando.